# No bundle for bundleID, SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

Every time i move to a specific scene in my SpriteKit game i get the following error in the console:

> no bundle for bundleID: (null)

What could be the reason for that? ..Why always at that specific scene? 
Thanks

Comment: Try doing a clean of your project.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've tracked down the origin of the **"no bundle for bundleID: (null)"** message by stepping through my app with the Xcode debugger.

It happens every time I report an achievement.

This line of code will trigger it for me:

```
[ GKAchievement reportAchievements:achievements withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if ( error != 0 )
        NSLog( @"Reporting of %@ failed: %@", achievement, [ error localizedDescription ] );
}];
```

That said, I am pretty sure it is benign, as my achievements and leader boards are working just fine.

As a side note: When I report a **GKScore**, instead of a **GKAchievement**, I don't see the same warning message.